# pass value to another php using ajax and javascript object..?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

when i tried to **json_decode** the **json.stringify data it returned NULL so used **json_last_error** to know the error and it returned the following error message

**Syntax error, malformed JSON**

**can anyone verify my ajax code enclosed in javascript function and spot the error ive done.**

**Below is the script code**

```
 <script>
 function callphp(){
 var dataa = {};
 dataa.dateipone = jQuery("#dateInputone").val();
 dataa.dateiptwo = jQuery("#dateInputtwo").val(); 
 dataa.ino = jQuery("#ino").val();
 dataa.submit = "submit";
 alert("Hello")
 $.ajax({
    url : "six-cuf.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data :JSON.stringify(dataa),
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success:function(data)
    {
        if(data){ 
          alert(data);   
          //console.log("Data from Server"+JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        else{
          console.log("Data is empty");
        } 
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status + " Message = " + xhr.statusText);
        //console.log('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status + " Message = " +  xhr.statusText);
    }
   });
 }
```

**Below is six-cuf.php**

```
  $data = json_decode($_POST['dataa']);
  print_r($data);

  switch (json_last_error()) {
   case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
         echo ' - No errors';
         break;
   case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
         echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
          break;
   case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
         echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
          break;
   case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
         echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
          break;
   case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
         echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
          break;
   case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
         echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
          break;
   default:
         echo ' - Unknown error';
         break;
   }

   if(isset($_POST["dateipone"],$_POST["dateiptwo"],$_POST["ino"],$_POST["options"],$_POST["dateone"],$_POST["datetwo"],$_POST["submit"]))
{

    //php code
}
```

**in dateipone,dateiptwo and dateone,datetwo...value of one this pair will be empty.**

Comment: You definitely have no `$_POST['dataa']` in your `$_POST`.

Comment: @u_mulder...are u saying that javascript object value is being not posted to my another php page..??

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and see what you have

Comment: @u_mulder..its just priniting an empty array like this**Array()** . can u just provide me with an example how to pass those values..im new to ajax and dont know much..itll be a help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to encode anything into json before passing to server. You can pass plain javascript object, browser will do the rest:

```
var dataa = {};
dataa.dateipone = jQuery("#dateInputone").val();
dataa.dateiptwo = jQuery("#dateInputtwo").val(); 
dataa.ino = jQuery("#ino").val();
dataa.submit = "submit";
$.ajax({
    url : "six-cuf.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataa,
    // no content-type here!
    success:function(data) {

    }
});
```

On server side check `$_POST` array as usual:

```
print_r($_POST);
// you will have keys: `dateipone`, `dateiptwo`, `ino` and `submit` in it
```